# onPostExecute not being called

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am having problems trying to get to onPostExecute to fire on this piece of code, I am new to  java and especially multithreading so if what i'm doing is completely wrong please feel free to correct me...need to learn.

So the problem is with this:

```
 public class DataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

 Context context;
    DataTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();        
    }
 // Global Int for counting how many Tasks have been completed
    int asynCount = 0;

    ArrayList<String> arr_dataVts=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_dataNtm=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_dataOdas=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_dataMetAll=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_dataMet3HrTask=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_dataTideTask=new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

     //VtsAsyncTask
    VtsTask task1 = new VtsTask();
    task1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    //NtmAsyncTask
    NtmTask task2 = new NtmTask();
    task2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    //OdasAsyncTask
    OdasTask task3 = new OdasTask();
    task3.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    //MetAllTask
    MetAllTask task4 = new MetAllTask();
    task4.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    //Met3HrTask
    Met3HrTask task5 = new Met3HrTask();
    task5.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    //TideTask
    TideTask task6 = new TideTask();
    task6.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

    return 1;
}
```

All the tasks execute as should do

but here in the onPostExecute:

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if (asynCount == 6){
         //start intents for main activity
        System.out.println("asynCount has reached= " + asynCount + " so now starting MainActivity");
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
          intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data1", arr_dataVts);
          intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data2", arr_dataNtm);
          intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data3", arr_dataOdas);
          intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data4", arr_dataMetAll);
          intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data5", arr_dataMet3HrTask);
          intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data6", arr_dataTideTask);
         // context.startActivity(intent);  
     }else{
       //update dialogue
     }
  }
}
```

The onPostExecute never gets called? I don't know why.
I have tried using Integers, Void and Booleans to get it to return but doesn't work. 
All advice is appreciated.
EDIT: I now realise that I should really be using Bundle here for all the extras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataTask` class is unnecessary. The only thing that you are doing in the background is starting several other AsyncTask's you don't need to wrap all of those execute() commands inside of the own AsyncTask because they already get executed in a background thread just by the very nature of AsyncTask.

Each of these other Tasks that you have needs to have it's own `onPostExecute()` that handles the results from that specific task and does something with it.

EDIT:

Here is some pseudocode of how it might look if you combined all of your operations into a single AsyncTask:

```
public class DataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    Context context;
    DataTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context; // <-- you already have a context, you don't need to call getApplicationContext();       
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        doSomeWork();
        doSomeOtherWork();
        doYetSomeMoreWork();
        //...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        doSomethingWithThe(result);
    }
}
```

The `doSomeWork()` etc... methods should not be AsyncTasks, just normal methods so that they execute sequentially. That way, when all of them are complete `onPostExecute()` will be called.

Comment: Hi, The reason why it was in its own class was so I can call it at anytime from my app, to update the ui. What would be the correct method...call all the tasks individually?

Comment: Yes, you could call them each individually. Also given the code that you've posted it looks like onPostExecute() probably is getting called but because of your if statement isn't actually doing anything. You initialize asycCount to 0, and then are checking if it is equal to 6 which it will never be, because you aren't ever changing it from 0.

Comment: sorry, my fault. asynCount gets added to each time one of the tasks finishes. I didn't include the code for the tasks but will do now..

Comment: so in the onPostExecute of the individual tasks I add 1 to the asynCount to have an idea when the all finnish so I could then move on to the next activity.

Comment: `onPostExecute()` inside of `DataTask` is going to get called immediately after you start all of your other tasks. It is not going to wait for them to finish. So asyncCount will still be 0 most likely. Add a log statement to the DataTask.onPostExecute() method so you can see when it runs, and what the value of `asyncCount` is.

Comment: AH..., yes you're right, its called straight away and is 0. Here I am learning to multithread and not picking up on that....so many things to think about, but thats why I am enjoying learning to code. So is there anyway I delay that until it reaches 6

Comment: Not any good way. You should use the `onPostExecute()` inside of each of your other Tasks to do whatever it is that you want with the data that they fetch individually. Or if you are dead set on clumping them together then do all six fetch operations inside of a single AsyncTask so that onPostExecute() won't get called until all of the work is complete.

Comment: Ok, If I do it all inside a single Task then it becomes quite slow around 10-15 sec for all the connections etc, that was why I turned to try multithreading. I can try the onPostExecute() in each of the task individually.

Comment: Thanks for your help, its 3:20am here so im off but please if you have any further thoughts don't hesitate i'm all ears. I'll leave it 24 hours before accepting your answer just in case anyone else has some input, Thanks again.